# C# alternative of OracleDataAdapter to access database

Tags: c#, oracle, datatable

I have someone else's C# code to retrieve data from a database looks like:

```
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            using (OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, conn))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dTable);
            }
        }
```

I have two concerns about the code.

1. as the SQL takes long to come back, the above code run 20 - 30 minutes to complete, during which time I couldn't monitor its progress.
2. If another SQL is applied and the resultset turned out to huge, can DataTable really handle it, I was expecting a OutOfMemory exception will occur.

In another word, I was looking for some alternative to the above OracleDataAdapter/DataTable combo, something like oldie-but-goodie JDBC stuff in Java. I know for sure something in C# like that must exist, but I am quite new to C# so can someone please give me a guide or code snippet to get started.

Comment: Any query that runs for 20/30 minutes has serious problems. First I would look at what you are trying to load and check if you can use some pagination on the data.

Comment: For the execution time there could be a lot of reason and you have not posted the query so it's hard to tell. But one very likely cause is lack of index. As for alternatives for a DataAdaptor/DataTable yes there is but it all depends on how you use the result.

Comment: If the DataTable is huge, then it is possible that you get out of memory error. If the result set of the query is that huge, then you should consider pagination. As others have mentioned, you might want to review your query's performance too.

Comment: thanks to all. There are some limits that tied my hands: I can't change the SQL as it's handed over to me; I can't index it since my understanding is that it'll get DBA involved which is out of the question. How do I do pagination BTW? Something like use the SQL clause "rownum>10 and rownum<20"? w.r.t an alternative, can I use SQLcommand/SqlDataReader? at least it seemed that I can read out the result row by row